# How to hide other images when the user loses?

Tags: java, processing

I'm making a flappy bird game, and in my code for if the bird collides with a pipe I made it so it displays a gameover screen if it does. It correctly displays the screen but it still shows the pipes and the bird on top of the gameover screen, I've tried using `boolean showimage = false` and that didn't seem to work, any guidance would be appreciated.

I also haven't added it in yet so the game stops when the user dies and I'm thinking that might be a reason why?

EDIT: It appears that Ii wasn't very clear so I apologize. I'm asking how to only show the gameover screen when the bird collides with a pipe (`isCollide`) however, it currently shows the pipes and birds above the gameover screen and I'm asking how to hide the bird and pipes and only show the gameover screen.

Here's my code for the game that's relevant to my problem, the full code can be found in the previous edits

```
import processing.serial.*;
PImage gameover;
PImage bg; //Declaring variables for images
PImage img;
PImage imgPipe;
Serial myPort;

void isCollide(Pipe myP) {
 if ((x + size > myP.pipeX) && (x < myP.pipeX + myP.pipeWidth) && (y <
   myP.upperBound)) {
  image(gameover, 0, 0);
 }

 if ((x + size > myP.pipeX) && (x < myP.pipeX + myP.pipeWidth) && (y + size >
   myP.lowerBound)) {
  image(gameover, 0, 0);
 }
}

void display() {
 pushMatrix();
 translate(x, y);
 fill(255);
 image(img, 0, 0, size, size);
 popMatrix();
}

void display() {
 stroke(0);
 fill(120, 90, 55);
 image(imgPipe, pipeX, upperBound - imgPipe.height); //Upper pipe image
 image(imgPipe, pipeX, lowerBound); //Lower Pipe image
}

void setup() {
 myPort = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[3], 9600); //Port the Arduino is 
 plugged into
 size(300, 500);
 bg = loadImage("background2.jpg"); //Loading images
 img = loadImage("bird.png");
 imgPipe = loadImage("wall2.png");
 myBird = new Bird();
 myPipe.renew();
 gameover = loadImage("gameover.png");
}

void draw() {
 background(bg); //Drawing background
 myPipe.update();
 myBird.control();
 myBird.isCollide(myPipe);

 myBird.display();
 myPipe.display();
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code to ask us to debug for you. Especially since we can't even run it because we don't have the serial device. Can you please narrow it down to a [mcve] that we can copy and paste to run ourselves?

Comment: @KevinWorkman hi, im not sure i would be able to make a copy for you since i made this using an arduino as a controller, i can update it to show the relevant pieces of code though

Comment: Whenever the collision happens, call `noLoop()`, and make sure that the game over screen is the last thing you draw in `draw()`

Comment: @MasterYushi The noLoop() ended the game, however the images are still being shown over the gameover image? Its like its acting as a bg

Comment: @AdamSteele Your question is about hiding an image, not about Arduino. For an example that shows the problem, you could just use a hardcoded image that you hide when you press a key.

Comment: @KevinWorkman i dont thin kmy question was clear enough to what i wanted then sorry, i will edit it to show that. I simply only want the gameover screen to be shown when the bird hits a pipe. However, currently its still got the pipes and bird itself being shown in front of the game over image. Sorry if it wasnt clear

Comment: @AdamSteele Right. You would want to create a separate example program that just does the one thing: shows an image (or better yet, just a rectangle) until you press a key. Get that working perfectly. Then move on and create an example program that shows an image or rectangle until another rectangle intersects it. Get that working perfectly. In other words, you need to [break your problem down into smaller steps](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and take on those steps one at a time. When you're stuck on a specific step, then you can ask a specific question here. Good luck.

Comment: @AdamSteele make `myBird.isCollide(myPipe)` the last line in `draw()`

Comment: @MasterYushi it worked thanks a bunch!